# Hong Kong transit visa for refugee travel document holder?

Tags: transit-visas, hong-kong, pakistani-citizens, refugees

I am travelling from Toronto to Colombo via Hong Kong. My nationality is Pakistani, but I am a refugee in Canada and am currently residing there, so I only have a Canadian travel document, and not a passport. Will I need a transit visa for Hong Kong?

I was denied boarding with Turkish Airlines because they said I had a travel document and my online ETA visa was not stamped, so they made it an issue and denied my boarding.

Comment: As I understand it, residents of Canada [do not need a transit visa for Hong Kong](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=HK&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX). You would need to show your Canada PR card (in addition to your refugee travel document) as proof of residence.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/), assuming you hold a valid Travel Document Convention 1951. With a Canadian PR card:

> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Those who are in direct (Air to Air or Air to Sea) transit if holding
>   confirmed onward bookings, continuing their journey within 48 hours
>   and not leaving the transit lounge.

Without a Canadian PR card:

> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Those who are in direct (Air to Air or Air to Sea) transit if holding
>   confirmed onward bookings, continuing their journey within 48 hours
>   and not leaving the transit lounge.

So I think the answer is you don't, and Turkish Airlines made a mistake, based on the information available.